# Sending data via broadcast

Tags: android, ioio

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback 
{
private Intent intent;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       if (activityReceiver != null)
{ 
       IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
      registerReceiver(activityReceiver, intentFilter);
}

    intent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
    startService(intent);

    }

 private BroadcastReceiver activityReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int value=intent.getIntExtra("VALUE", 0);
    txtData.setText(""+value);
    }}

}
```

SERVICE

```
public class Service extends IOIOService {
//Intent intent=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
private final int BUTTON_PIN = 34;
@Override
protected IOIOLooper createIOIOLooper() {
    return new BaseIOIOLooper() {
        private DigitalOutput led_;
        private DigitalInput mButton;
        int  oneTime = 0;



        @Override
        protected void setup() throws ConnectionLostException,
                InterruptedException {
            led_ = ioio_.openDigitalOutput(IOIO.LED_PIN);
            mButton = ioio_.openDigitalInput(BUTTON_PIN, DigitalInput.Spec.Mode.PULL_UP);
        }

        @Override
        public void loop() throws ConnectionLostException,
                InterruptedException {

             final boolean reading1 = mButton.read();
             if (reading1) 
             {
                 led_.write(false);
                 if(oneTime == 0)
                 {
                                             Intent intent = new Intent();
                     intent.putExtra("VALUE", 100);
                     sendBroadcast(intent);
                     oneTime = 1;
                 }

                          } 
             else 

             {
                               led_.write(true);
                             }
            Thread.sleep(100);
              }

    };
}
}
  @Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null
            && intent.getAction().equals("stop")) {
        // User clicked the notification. Need to stop the service.
        nm.cancel(0);
        stopSelf();
    } else 
    {
        // Service starting. Create a notification.
        Notification notification = new Notification(
                R.drawable.ic_launcher, "IOIO service running",
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification
                .setLatestEventInfo(this, "IOIO Service", "Click to stop",
                        PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(
                                "stop", null, this, this.getClass()), 0));
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        nm.notify(0, notification);
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return(null);

}
```

}
I am trying to send an integer value from service to activity using broadcast and displaying that integer into a textbox in activity. Its a simple thing but still my program is getting crashed. This is a part of my code where i have added the code for broadcasting. Can anyone please tell me whats wrong in this ? Is there anything to add more ?

Comment: post your logcat as well

Comment: post ur ioioservice, code.

Comment: @sush its already der

Comment: @user3040168 yes its there but its been extended. original code lies in IOIOService class. hope that extends service class and its proper, else with this code hard to find out the issue.

Comment: look at my answer. hope it can help

Comment: The stacktrace is not from the code you posted. You have already commented out the part that causes it (initializing an `Intent` member variable of the service at object init time when Service is not usable as Context). Please post the actual code/problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onCreate()` change the below lines :

```
   intent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
    startService(new Intent(this, Service.class));
```

to this:

```
intent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
startService(intent);
```

**EDITED:**

```
//send broadcast from activity to all receivers listening to the action 
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("VALUE", 100);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And fetch the value in the activity's `onRecieve()` method.

Register the Broadcast in activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback 
{
private Intent intent;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    intent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
    startService(intent);
if (activityReceiver != null)
  {
           IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        //Map the intent filter to the receiver
         registerReceiver(activityReceiver, intentFilter);
  }

}

 private BroadcastReceiver activityReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "received message in activity..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           int value=intent.getIntExtra("VALUE", 0);
           txtData.setText(value);
    }
};


 }
```

Comment: Tried it earlier ...still crashing

Comment: I think the issue is with the this line `Intent intent=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);` in your service class. As its not able to get the context. Just comment this line and then check @user3040168

Comment: Yes it worked without crashing but the code in service is nt executed...the integer is not passed.

Comment: In your code the intent is null that is why its not getting the value.

Comment: @GrlHu But then when i command Intent intent=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);, it asks to intialize the "intent"

Comment: @GrlsHu should we declare "ACTION_STRING_ACTIVITY" as a constant that has to be passed to the activity

Comment: No need of that i had just shown for understanding only. Check out my updated answer. @user3040168

Comment: @GrlHu I have edited the code as you suggested..but nothin is passed..In on recieve method the value is displayed in the textbox...nothing is displayed...

Comment: You have not registered your activity to recieve the broadcast that is why its not getting the value. Check out the tutorial it will help you. http://androidexperinz.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/communication-between-service-and-activity-part-1/

Comment: Let me know if any query.

Comment: @GrlsHu thanks i read that...am using broadcast first time....what i understood is...to recieve anything u need to create a broadcast reciever and then u need to register this reciever. am i right ?

Comment: @GrlsHu i have edited my code...could you pls check it out.. i am confused wid this line... IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();

Comment: Check for the null value in your broadcast reciever as i have checked in activity.

Comment: @GrlsHu  do we need to unregister it anywhere if it registered ?

Comment: Yes you need to unregister it in `onDestroy` like `@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("Service", "onDestroy");
//STEP3: Unregister the receiver
        unregisterReceiver(activityReceiver);
    }`

Comment: @GrlsHu on adding unregisteration also its nt working..ther is no error in logcat also hw cn i find the bug?

Comment: @GrlsHu   logcat is error free...only the thing is it is not dispalyed

Comment: @GrlsHu i tried by passing a string and it worked...thanks my actual intention is done

Answer (score 0):

declare service in manifest.

```
<service
                android:name=".Service">
 </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
             // cuase for null pointer exception, intent is getting set as null first
then ur using putExtra method on it.  
              Intent intent = null;
                 intent.putExtra("VALUE", 100);
                 sendBroadcast(intent);
                 oneTime = 1;
```

Comment: intent.putExtra("VALUE", 100);...dis line is asking for initializing the "intent"...since Intent intent=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); is not used